# set the 3D animations in three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm studying this example http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_morphtargets_md2_control.html found on this site: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/ in which files are contained in the rules that indicate three.js the way in which the models must move 3d?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using chrome developer tools you can go Chrome > View > Developer Tools >Developer tools.
In the Sources tab there is all the files used in the example.
What you are looking is in the file "MD2CharacterComplex.js", there you will find all animations on this examples.
Cheers.